# Could someone help solving a Pandas error when saving a csv file with python-requests?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Could someone help me understand why this code thrown an error and provide a solution how I could save my file on my local machine:

```
myLast = result[:1]

for x in myLast:
    urldailyLocal= os.path.basename(x)
    s=requests.get(x, verify=False).content
    c=pd.read_csv(s)
    c.to_csv('path/to/my/file/'+urldailyLocal, index=False)
```

error after running the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 448, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 694, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
 OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

`myLast` list stores an url in such format:

```
'https://test.com/something/example_2020-09-27-10.51PST_ALL.csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work for you

```
s = requests.get(x, verify=False).content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```